# How to get namespaced function to work from eval

Tags: clojure

Say, I have a file that begins with:

`(ns example.utils
  (:require [example.db.core :as db]))`

Now, I need to evaluate a function call from db namespace knowing the name of a function as a string. This is needed as name of the function is not known at runtime and determined dynamically.

`(eval (list (read-string "db/get-user") {:id 18}))`

The problem is, i get "unknown namespace" error, even though

`(db/get-user {:id 18})`

works just fine.

Any idea why is it so? I tried importing the functions as `[... :refer :all]` but they are invisible in the current namespace anyway.

Even more strangely, this works in REPL but does not work in the application.

EDIT:

After evaluating the answers I came to a conclusion that my situation might stem from using eval inside compojure-api macros. Am I right here?

```
(defapi service-routes
  (ring.swagger.ui/swagger-ui "/api/v1/docs" :swagger-docs "/apiv1.json")

  (swagger-docs "/apiv1.json" 
     {:info {:title "Example API"
      :description "Version 1"}})
  (context* "/api/v1" []
        :tags ["API v1"]
   ......
```

I kind of 'solved' the issue by adding `(require '[example.db.core :as db])` just before the eval call. This seems stinky but suffices for now.

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to do here?  `eval` is rarely used.  There is probably another way.  I suspect your error is in the string-list-eval line, not the namespacing.

Comment: (eval (read-string "db/get-user")) gives the same error. If there is another way just write an answer. Such comments as yours are pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example works fine for me. Using the raw boilerplate provided by `lein new`, which includes a function `foo`, I then created a new ns with this:

```
(ns so.nstest
  (:require [so.core :as whatevs]))
```

Then from the repl I did this:

```
so.nstest> (eval (list (read-string "whatevs/foo") 66))
66 Hello, World!
nil
```

So it worked fine. However, while not your issue, you should almost never use `read-string` because it is dangerous; use `clojure.edn/read-string` instead if you really must do it:

`(eval (list (clojure.edn/read-string "whatevs/foo") 66))`

This line also worked when I placed it in the `so.nstest` source file and evaluated that file, so it wasn't a REPL-only success.

Your issue must lie somewhere else.

Comment: This is really interesting. Seems that my problems might stem from using those functions inside a macro ( 'defroutes' from compojure-api) that might do something with namespacing inside it. While it does not immediately solve my issue, it actually answers my question :)

Comment: Btw. read-string is not dangerous as long as strings to be evaluated come from well controlled environment (in this case another module of the same app without user access).

Comment: @Terminus unless you have a specific reason why you cannot use clojure.edn/read-string, you should use it instead of core/read-string. Always write safe code by default.

Comment: This boils down to philosophy. Let's take `if` statement from C. Most people say it is dangerous not to put braces around it. Yet, it is really aesthetically pleasing not to put them. I know a person that never puts them and had 0 bugs connected to it. Braceless if is in the grammar for a reason, the same goes to read-string. It all boils down to cost vs. perceived danger, which is always subjective. You can invent "golden rules" to guide novice programmers, but they are not universally true even if most people adhere to them.